# How can i interact with Hardhat smart contract in Angular Project?

Tags: angular, blockchain, web3js, hardhat

I created a Hardhat project and I deployed a smart contract locally. also I Interact with it by an Interact.Js file.

now I want to interact with this contract on an Angular Project.. how can I do that?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;


import { ERC721 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";




contract NonFunToken is ERC721, Ownable {

   NonFunToken.sol  

// Constructor will be called on contract creation
    constructor() ERC721("NonFunToken", "NONFUN") {}

    // Allows minting of a new NFT 
    function mintCollectionNFT(address collector, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner() {
        _safeMint(collector, tokenId); 
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
deploy.js

```
// We require the Hardhat Runtime Environment explicitly here. This is optional
// but useful for running the script in a standalone fashion through `node <script>`.
//
// You can also run a script with `npx hardhat run <script>`. If you do that, Hardhat
// will compile your contracts, add the Hardhat Runtime Environment's members to the
// global scope, and execute the script.

const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  // Get the contract owner
  const contractOwner = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log(`Deploying contract from: ${contractOwner[0].address}`);

  // Hardhat helper to get the ethers contractFactory object
  const NonFunToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('NonFunToken');

  // Deploy the contract
  console.log('Deploying NonFunToken...');
  const nonFunToken = await NonFunToken.deploy();
  await nonFunToken.deployed();
  console.log(`NonFunToken deployed to: ${nonFunToken.address}`)
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
// scripts/interact.js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    console.log('Getting the non fun token contract...\n');
    
    const contractAddress = '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3';
    const nonFunToken = await ethers.getContractAt('NonFunToken', contractAddress);
    const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
    
   // name()
   console.log('Querying NFT collection name...');
   const name = await nonFunToken.name();
   console.log(`Token Collection Name: ${name}\n`);

   // symbol()
    console.log('Querying NFT collection symbol...');
    const symbol = await nonFunToken.symbol();
    console.log(`Token Collection Symbol: ${symbol}\n`);

     // Mint new NFTs from the collection using custom function mintCollectionNFT()
     console.log('Minting a new NFT from the collection to the contractOwner...');
     const contractOwner = signers[0].address;
     const initialMintCount = 10; // Number of NFTs to mint
     let initialMint = [];
     for (let i = 1; i <= initialMintCount; i++) {
         let tx = await nonFunToken.mintCollectionNFT(signers[0].address, i.toString());
         await tx.wait(); // wait for this tx to finish to avoid nonce issues
         initialMint.push(i.toString());
     }
     console.log(`${symbol} NFT with tokenIds ${initialMint} and minted to: ${contractOwner}\n`);

     // balanceOf()
    console.log(`Querying the balance count of contractOwner ${contractOwner}...`);
    let contractOwnerBalances = await nonFunToken.balanceOf(contractOwner);
    console.log(`${contractOwner} has ${contractOwnerBalances} NFTs from this ${symbol} collection\n`);

     // ownerOf()
     const NFT1 = initialMint[0];
     console.log(`Querying the owner of ${symbol}#${NFT1}...`);
     const owner = await nonFunToken.ownerOf(NFT1);
     console.log(`Owner of NFT ${symbol} ${NFT1}: ${owner}\n`);


     // safeTransferFrom()
    const collector = signers[1].address;
    console.log(`Transferring ${symbol}#${NFT1} to collector ${collector}...`);
    // safeTransferFrom() is overloaded (ie. multiple functions with same name) hence differing syntax
    await nonFunToken["safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)"](contractOwner, collector, NFT1);
    console.log(`${symbol}#${NFT1} transferred from ${contractOwner} to ${collector}`);
    console.log(`Querying the owner of ${symbol}#${NFT1}...`);
    let NFT1Owner = await nonFunToken.ownerOf(NFT1);
    console.log(`Owner of ${symbol}#${NFT1}: ${NFT1Owner}\n`);

    // approve()
    console.log(`Approving contractOwner to spend collector ${symbol}#${NFT1}...`);
    // Creates a new instance of the contract connected to the collector
    const collectorContract = nonFunToken.connect(signers[1]); 
    await collectorContract.approve(contractOwner, NFT1);
    console.log(`contractOwner ${contractOwner} has been approved to spend collector ${collector} ${symbol}#${NFT1}\n`);

    // getApproved()
    console.log(`Getting the account approved to spend ${symbol}#${NFT1}...`);
    let NFT1Spender = await nonFunToken.getApproved(NFT1);
    console.log(`${NFT1Spender} has the approval to spend ${symbol}#${NFT1}\n`);

    // safeTransferFrom() with valid approve()
    console.log(`Transferring ${symbol}#${NFT1} from collector ${collector} to contractOwner ${contractOwner} using contractOwner wallet...`);
    // Calling the safeTransferFrom() using the contractOwner instance
    await nonFunToken["safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)"](collector, contractOwner, NFT1);
    NFT1Owner = await nonFunToken.ownerOf(NFT1);
    console.log(`Owner of ${symbol}#${NFT1}: ${NFT1Owner}\n`);

    // setApprovalForAll()
    console.log(`Approving collector to spend all of contractOwner ${symbol} NFTs...`);
    // Using the contractOwner contract instance as the caller of the function
    await nonFunToken.setApprovalForAll(collector, true) // The second parameter can be set to false to remove operator
    console.log(`collector ${collector} has been approved to spend all of contractOwner ${contractOwner} ${symbol} NFTs\n`);

      // isApprovedForAll()
      console.log(`Checking if collector has been approved to spend all of contractOwner ${symbol} NFTs`);
      const approvedForAll = await nonFunToken.isApprovedForAll(contractOwner, collector);
      console.log(`Is collector ${collector} approved to spend all of contractOwner ${contractOwner} ${symbol} NFTs: ${approvedForAll}\n`);

       // safeTransferFrom() with valid isApprovedForAll()
    console.log(`Validating collector has approval to transfer all of contractOwner NFTs...`);
    // contractOwner NFT count before transfer
    contractOwnerBalances = await nonFunToken.balanceOf(contractOwner);
    console.log(`BEFORE: ${contractOwner} has ${contractOwnerBalances} NFTs from this ${symbol} collection`);
    let collectorBalances = await nonFunToken.balanceOf(collector);
    console.log(`BEFORE: ${collector} has ${collectorBalances} NFTs from this ${symbol} collection`);
    console.log(`Collector transferring all contractOwner NFTs to collector wallet`);
    for (let i = 0; i < initialMint.length; i++) {
        // Using the collector wallet to call the transfer
        await collectorContract["safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)"](contractOwner, collector, initialMint[i]);
    }
    console.log(`NFT transfer completed`);
    contractOwnerBalances = await nonFunToken.balanceOf(contractOwner);
    console.log(`AFTER: ${contractOwner} has ${contractOwnerBalances} NFTs from this ${symbol} collection`);
    collectorBalances = await nonFunToken.balanceOf(collector);
    console.log(`AFTER: ${collector} has ${collectorBalances} NFTs from this ${symbol} collection`);

  




     
    
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exitCode = 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular app is usually a **separate project** to your contract projects. You'll also usually **not** use hardhat inside your Angular app.

---

To use a contract inside your Frontend dApp (e.g. written in Angular), you need to:

1. Import `ethers` (not from Hardhat)

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";
```

2. Inject your credentials from the Wallet

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
```

3. Create an object of your contact using ABI

```js
const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_ABI, signer);
```

---

I recommend doing a tutorial on dApps, e.g. [Buildspace: Build your first Ethereum dApp](https://buildspace.so/builds/solidity) is a good one.

Comment: in fact I created a project Hardhat  (nft store normally) and I depolyed the contracts and I also created the interaction script (the file above) .. now to use the functions of the interact file. js in my frontend.. (in components).